# Unwanted shortcut for switching to the next input source for Ububtu 20

Tags: system-installation, 20.04, system-settings

After upgrading to a new lts ubuntu 20.04 it suggested me to add a new shortcut for switching input source as ctrl + shift.

I agree, but later I figure it wasn't a good idea, how can I disable it.

Settings -> Region & Language - only show me that extra shortcut is available, but I'm not allowed to change it

[image]

Settings -> Keyboard Shortcuts - shows only one shortcut

[image]

Thank you